# Android Connection Presistence

Tags: android

Does Android keep the connection between the server/socket when it moves from EDGE to WIFI and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from Edge to WiFi requires the device to re-negotiate it's IP Address.  So yes, it will cut whatever connections are active at time of switch-over.

Answer (score 0):

It does not keep the connection open, but it does not explicitly close it either - if you are reading on the socket when WiFi starts up, you will not get EOF back on your read! You will need to detect the connectivity change using a BroadcastReceiver, and close down the socket yourself.

Comment: i might got something similar that happened strangely @AirsourceLtd,... lately both of my Android devices are trying to connect one another. One acting as AP, and another one act as Client. First, they connected successfully. But when the client try to connecting a socket to that AP, its connection always refused. Is there something wrong?